# Site icons appear to have slipped again

Tags: bug, favicon

My current inbox:

[image]

Given that the room in question is not associated with QA... I think there's a bug swimming in this pool :)

Comment: I thought Charcoal and Smokey are assuring the quality of SE? ;)